# Passing property to nested component not live updating. (Livewire 3)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm building a form here with an address area where the user can search for it's postal code if they doesn't know it.
It's structured like this:

1. A parent **CreateUser** livewire component with the whole form.

   - The component has all the form fields as properties `public string $address_city;` and so on...
   - All the inputs contain the appropriate `wire:model`.
2. A child **PostalCodeSearch** livewire component with the contents that show up on a modal.

- The component has 3 properties required for the API call to search for a Postal Code, namely `$state`  `$city`  `$street`.
- The `mount()`  method then calls the function to search the API and returns the object to the view.

On my `create-user.blade.php`, I implemented a version of [Pines](https://devdojo.com/pines/docs/modal)' modal. And it's being called like this:

```
<button type="button" @click="modalOpen = true">Search Postal Code</button>
<template x-teleport="body">
  <livewire:admin.postal-code-search :state="$address_state" />
</template>
```

Notice the `:state="$address_state"`? That's how I've been trying to pass the parent livewire component properties to the children. At first, it actually works, when I declare a default on my parent component, like `public $address_state = 'es'` . But everytime it changes on the live component, it doesn't update.

I've read the docs on Nested Components, watched the screencast, but all stuff that's said regarding the parent component is related to using `$parent` on Alpine, which it's not my case and/or I'm not getting how to use in this particular case.

---

Livewire/Admin/CreateUser.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use Livewire\Component;

class CreateUser extends Component
{
    public string $address_country;
    public string $address_state;
    public string $address_city;
    public string $address_postalcode;
    public string $address_street;
    public string $address_number;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('admin.livewire.user.create');
    }
}
```

---

views/admin/livewire/user/create.blade.php

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <div 
            x-ref="address_container"
            x-data="{
                modalOpen: false,
            }"
            @keydown.escape.window="modalOpen = false"
        >
            <label>Country</label>
                <select wire:model='address_country' x-ref="country_select">
                    <option value="bra">Brazil</option>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </select>
            <label>State</label>
                <select wire:model='address_state' x-ref="state_select">
                    <option value="br-es">Espirito Santo</option>
                    <!-- ... -->
                </select>
            <label>City</label>
                <input type="text" x-ref="city_input" wire:model='address_city' />
            <label>Postal Code</label>
                <input type="text" x-ref="cep_input" wire:model='address_postalcode'/>
            <label>Street</label>
                <input type="text" x-ref="street_input" wire:model='address_street'/>
            <label>Number</label>
                <input type="text" x-ref="number_input" wire:model='address_number'/>
            <label>Complement</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model='address_complement'/>
            <label>Locality</label>
                <input type="text" wire:model='address_locality'/>

            <button type="button"
                @click="modalOpen = true"
            >Search Postal Code</button>
                <p x-text.live="$wire.address_state"></p>
            
            <template x-teleport="body">
                <livewire:admin.postal-code-search :state="$address_state" :city="$address_city" :street="$address_street" />
            </template>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

---

Livewire/Admin/PostalCodeSearch.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;

class PostalCodeSearch extends Component
{
    public string $state;
    public string $city;
    public string $street;
    public array $postalCodes;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->postalCodeSearch();
    }

    public function postalCodeSearch()
    {
        $this->postalCodes = [];

        try {
            $client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/']);

            $response = $client->request('GET',
                Str::upper($this->state) .
                '/' .
                htmlspecialchars($this->city) .
                '/' .
                htmlspecialchars($this->street) .
                '/json'
            );
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return;
        }

        if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
            $json = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());
            if (sizeof($json) != 0) {
                $this->postalCodes = $json;
            }
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('admin.livewire.modal.postal-code', [
            'postalCodes' => $this->postalCodes
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

views/admin/livewire/modal/postalcode.blade.php

```
<div role="dialog" aria-modal="true"
    x-cloak
    x-show="modalOpen"
>
    <div>
        <div aria-modal="true"
            x-trap.inert.noscroll="modalOpen"
        >
            @if ($postalCodes)
            <ul>
                @foreach ($postalCodes as $code)
                <li>{{ $code->cep }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The *mount()* method is only called once and that might be the problem, but it would be better if you could post all the relevant code to get a more precise answer

Comment: @Pippo, I edited the question including a cleaned-up version of the code. I removed the classes and some other cosmetic stuff for clarity reasons. The whole structure is essentially there.
P.S.: I'm using ChoicesJS for the <select>, so, to keep it simple I put an example for the basic syntax here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now it's clearer.
To allow child component properties to be updated when the same change in the parent component, you need to set the *#[Reactive]* attribute for them:

```php
use Livewire\Attributes\Reactive; // <--- note also this

class PostalCodeSearch extends Component
{
    #[Reactive]
    public string $state;

    #[Reactive]
    public string $city;

    #[Reactive]
    public string $street;

    // .....
```